# How to make my websites content available as Tor .onion and clearnet .com

Tags: configuration

I'm running a website with Nginx which I would like to be accessible by Tor and by clearnet. Currently it's only reachable by clearnet, e.g. www.example.com.

Of course people just can go to www.example.com through Tor browser, but I want to have a .onion address too for the same website.

I want the website and content to be accessible by www.example.com/ and xyzsfexample.onion/.
So they see content from /var/www/www.example.com/web/index.php as xyzsfexample.onion/index.php ; IF they browse on xyzsfexample.onion ; IF they browse on example.com they should see example.com/index.php

How do I set this up and how must Nginx be configured to do both?

Answer (score 1):

What you can use is nginx url rewrite.

There are many examples on stack overflow. One example is :

Nginx rewrite domain and URLs
https://stackoverflow.com/q/14565382/485626

you detect what url they requested and then rewrite it properly so that it can be used on any of the two domains.

Comment: you should not do it! First you will create a data leak and second you will turn your CMS haywire, I've tried this myself - there's no other correct solution but the one I've described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need anything except the NGinx and tor running on the same box: in nginx *server* block you utilize the include ability - so you will have two server blocks for defining listening address - a clearnet IP for open web and 127.0.0.7 for Tor - and *separate* logging, **separate** HTTPS certificates with corresponding host names in them to avoid collisions and data leaks **and** an environment variable for the darknet connection like DARKNET=1 or 0 correspondingly. Why do you need a variable? - To turn off *any* stats, ads and trackers for a darknet site to avoid privacy leaks: you do it on your CMS level by disabling blocks by the environmental variable value. You don't need **anything** else! As soon as you will make these server directives for http to https redirecting and for https site serving - just put the rest of your website config into the separate config file and include it as the last directive inside the https server definition block. That's it!

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/alecmuffett/eotk

This is a way to do it.
There is also a way to do it with OnionShare.
https://onionshare.org/

Comment: Read the README for eotk and you will understand why it's totally not a good idea. And OninShare serves a way different purpose - the answer is misleading